# Do user mode processes have to change to kernel mode to access /proc and /sys filesystems

Tags: linux, proc

*Computer Systems: a Programmer's Perspective* says

> Processors typically provide this capability with a mode bit in some control
> register that characterizes the privileges that the process currently enjoys. When
> the mode bit is set, the process is running in kernel mode (sometimes called
> supervisor mode). A process running in kernel mode can execute any instruction
> in the instruction set and access any memory location in the system.

> When the mode bit is not set, the process is running in user mode. A process
> in user mode is not allowed to execute privileged instructions that do things such
> as halt the processor, change the mode bit, or initiate an I/O operation. Nor is it
> allowed to directly reference code or data in the kernel area of the address space.
> Any such attempt results in a fatal protection fault. User programs must instead
> access kernel code and data indirectly via the system call interface.

> A process running application code is initially in user mode. The only
> way for the process to change from user mode to kernel mode is via an
> exception such as an interrupt, a fault, or a trapping system call.
> When the exception occurs, and control passes to the exception
> handler, the processor changes the mode from user mode to kernel mode.
> The handler runs in kernel mode. When it returns to the application
> code, the processor changes the mode from kernel mode back to user
> mode.
>
> Linux provides a clever mechanism, called **the /proc ﬁlesystem, that
> allows user mode processes to access the contents of kernel data
> structures**. The /proc ﬁlesystem exports the contents of many kernel
> data structures as a hierarchy of text ﬁles that can be read by user programs. For example, you can use the /proc ﬁlesystem to ﬁnd out general system attributes such as CPU type (/proc/cpuinfo), or
> the memory segments used by a particular process (/proc/process-id/maps). The
> 2.6 version of the Linux kernel introduced a /sys ﬁlesystem, which exports additional low-level information about system buses and devices.

When user mode processes   "access the contents of kernel data structures" via /proc and /sys ﬁlesystems, do they have to "change from user mode to kernel mode" "via an exception such as an interrupt, a fault, or a trapping system call"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any access to a file goes through either system calls or memory access traps (for memory-mapped files), so yes, processes switch to kernel mode to access files (and not only in `/proc` and `/sys`).

Comment: Thanks. The quote says "Nor is it allowed to directly reference code or data in the kernel area of the address space. Any such attempt results in a fatal protection fault. User programs must instead access kernel code and data indirectly via the system call interface."  Is "access the contents of kernel data structures via /proc and /sys ﬁlesystems" a way  (and the only) way to "access kernel code and data indirectly via the system call interface"?

Comment: It’s a way, but it’s not the only way; system calls also provide access to kernel code (to run it) and data (or rather, copies thereof).

Comment: Perhaps some of the confusion will be alleviated if I point out that `/proc` and `/sys` don’t magically give access to kernel data structures; they are turned into function calls in the kernel which allow reading and writing certain values from kernel objects (in `/sys`) or specific representations of kernel data (in `/proc`). Accesses are always mediated, it’s not like getting a pointer to kernel memory.